# Driver not detecting hardware on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I have the GTX 770M - Sager NP8265. Windows 10 64bit latest windows updates.

I used to have the drivers working well then switched to Ubuntu for a while and it worked then as well. I recently switched back to Windows 10 and it says "the graphics driver could not find compatible".

I know that the 770M isn't part of the Fermi generation so it should install. Nevertheless, I used DDU to remove it and reinstall the driver. Didn't work - I formatted my laptop and installed a couple year old driver. Didn't work - I formatted my laptop and updated to latest version of windows then installed a driver that was a year old 391.35. Didn't work.

I installed GeForce Experience and it says Unable to download the recommended driver.

I download TechPowerUp GPU-Z and it says GTX 770M - therefore it does exist I'm not going crazy. But, Windows Basic Display Driver has been used this entire time.

I'd like to give this one more shot before having to go back to Ubuntu.

Comment: I have a GTX 770, and it's supported by both the current drivers and GeForce Experience, which means the GTX 770M is supported.  Can you be more specific than "lastest windows update"?  That doesn't tell me anything about which build you are running, which updates were last installed, nothing that can help me identify the reason you are unable to install drivers fr your display device.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not on the computer right now so I'll have to get back to you on that - it doesn't seem to be an issue with build/update as I tried on a 2015 and 2017 ISO with the same results - but it's update 1803 just not sure about build number right now

Answer (score 0):

Why are you installing old drivers ?

I suggest :

1. Go to the
   [NVIDIA Driver Downloads page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)
   and click on the *Graphics Drivers* button
   and let it decide on the best package to download.
   This requires either using Internet Explorer or having Java installed.
2. Go to the Device Manager, Display adapters section, right-click the GTX
   and choose Uninstall device (with driver if you are given the option).
   You will then need to use the power switch to reboot
   and Windows will install its generic driver.
3. Install the driver package that was previously downloaded and reboot.

Comment: I tried old drivers - they didn't work. I tried the newest drivers first, I'm just mentioning everything I tried. I don't have GTX in device manager, just Microsoft Basic Display Driver - I tried the steps you mentioned.

Comment: If you can't see the GTX in Device Manager, then you should use the first option in the NVIDIA Driver Downloads page and manually specify your display adapter. If after installing the downloaded package and rebooting the GTX is still missing, then unfortunately it has a hardware problem.